# How to set constants in an ansible role?

Tags: variables, constants, ansible, role

In an ansible role, i need to define constants for some paths, not changeable by users in their playbook.

Here's my need:

the role will have a **{{app_base_path}}** variable (changeable by user), and then i want to set 2 constants:

- app_instance_path: "{{app_base_path}}/appinstance"
- app_server_path: "{{app_instance_path}}/appserver"

I need each value several times in my tasks so i can't set only one variable for it

What's the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, ansible has no constants.

You can do the following:
In the file `<rolname>/defaults/main.yml`

```
---
# Don't change this variables
app_instance_path: "{{ app_base_path }}/appinstance"
app_server_path: "{{ app_instance_path }}/appserver"
```

And add an assertion task in to the `<rolename>/tasks/main.yml` file:

```
---
# ...
- name: Check some constants
  assert:
    that:
      - "app_instance_path == app_base_path + '/appinstance'"
      - "app_server_path == app_instance_path + '/appserver'"
```

Further more you can document for the users to only set `app_base_path` and leave `app_instance_path` and `app_server_path` as it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's not exactly what i expected but checking is a cool feature to force some paths.

Comment: How useful would these assertions be in practise?  Another role or task may easily change these variables after the role tests the assertions.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i got it with **set_fact**, unfortunately, it seems to have a very low priority in variables order, so my role execution can fail if the user defines extra_vars in his playbook...